# Regex for Numbers with Optional Decimal

Tags: javascript

I need a regex where the user can insert 8 digits (e.g 12345678) or 9 if it's decimal (e.g. 12345678.1) ou 10 if with 2 float point (e.g 12345678.10)

So far I can only get to this:

```
/^(\d{1,8})$/
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^\d{1,8}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

The second part `(\.\d{1,2})?` denotes the decmial.

Comment: Escape the `.` otherwise it'll consider `1234567x12` as valid.

Comment: My bad, I overlooked it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: If I put `11111111111` (11 digits) it says it is ok `validator="/^\d{1,8}(.\d{1,2})?$/"`

Comment: Check the updated answer. I missed escaping the `.` .